# Problem to load css with jquery in IE8

Tags: css, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem loading css with ajax, when I execute ajax in explorer and in the response i have this in the html

```
<style media="all" type="text/css">
    @import "/resources/calendar/calendar.css";
</style>
```

jQuery dont execute the request in explorer 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing something like this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="urlToStylesheet.css">
```

The standard way of loading an external stylesheet?